# How to curl ajax page?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I would like to know is there a way to crawl a page that show data through ajax.

Particularly, I would like to crawl this [website data](http://www.dmcc.ae/business-directory)

and need detailed answer with example of the above site.

Comment: inspect the ajax requests done with the browser developer tools, send them with `curl` ?

Comment: Why not just crawl the links that are loaded using the ajax requests?

Comment: @jerodev Can you provide one of the link?

Answer (score 1):

I see request is done through $.getJSON() in HTML that is why it is not visible in firebug console, here is example of [link](https://dmcc.secure.force.com/services/apexrest/DMCC_BusinessDirectory_API_1/get/?callback=jQuery172009522705371977402_1449045299674&authToken=1449045189372&page_num=1&query_type=activities&_=1449045301722)

Comment: The main page is being fetched through above link, Let me know full detail to get above link and subsequent pages data as well.

Comment: Kindly provide subsequent page solution so I can accept this answer.

Comment: Actually i don't have any solution for that i just answers to your request to provide one of the ajax links from that page - "@jerodev Can you provide one of the link?"